# Iterate through each child node separately in XML file

Tags: xml, xamarin.android

I would like to iterate through each child node separately and print value in Toast. For example, i want to print each author node separately in Toast: Toast nr 1: "Gambardella, Matthew" , Toast nr 2: "Ralls, Kim" and etc. How can i do it?

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
  <catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to get book author from XML file and display in Xamarin.Android project.

Please using the following code to do this.

Firstly, put your xml file in Asset folder and set **Build Action as AndroidAsset**, then

```
var context = Android.App.Application.Context;

        var durtion = ToastLength.Long;           
        AssetManager assets = this.Assets;        
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(assets.Open("Books.xml")))
        {
            //var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Book>));
            //books = (List<Book>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(content);
            foreach(XmlNode item in doc.ChildNodes[1])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ChildNodes[0].InnerText);
                //Toast.MakeText(context, item.ChildNodes[0].InnerText, durtion).Show();
            }                 

        }
```

If you want to get read xml file from Xamarin.Forms project, you can also take a look [File Handling in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows)

Comment: Basically, I would like to run each authors value in separately Toast, not all in one.

Comment: @LILO Toast.show() is asynchronous. The toast will not be displayed until the current method returns, and even then, Android may decide to show it at a later time (for example if there is already another toast displayed on the screen) or even not at all.